# Do popular questions and answers get exceptions?

Tags: discussion

For example, this question:

[An English expression for 'femme fatale'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171313/an-english-expression-for-femme-fatale)

**1.** There is almost all answers are in this question also:
[Feminine equivalent for Casanova](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133409/feminine-equivalent-for-casanova)

Questions are different but come to the same thing and answers. Is it ok or an exception to keep the newer question then? What value does it add?

**2.** In my opinion, most upvoted answer is not an answer to the question but it is still kept. I recommended him to give details but he refused to do that. Why would this answer be kept?

OP already mentioned that the phrase has become part of English and he is looking for alternatives. Maybe, the title of the question is misleading and I recommended OP to modify it also.

Note: I deleted my comments there. Also, I didn't vote as a duplicate because I wanted to ask your opinions.

---

Other than that, there is this question:
[Is there a word for some kind of incorrect empathy?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171302/is-there-a-word-for-some-kind-of-incorrect-empathy#comment357621_171302)

It did not become a popular question but in my opinion it is a good question. Yes, OP could be more clear but it touches upon different and related topics. The main question is a general concept but the example he gave goes into details. In the end, they were all related to empathy in some way.

It was put on hold because it is unclear after he clarified the question also. Yes it was unclear a bit first but he made an effort to clarify it. Also, I spent time to give valuable information (it could be someone else also) and I was going to modify the answer to make it more clear when I get confirmation from him based on comments.

---

I just wanted to make my point and talk about my observations. I wanted to get your insight also regarding to these situations. Maybe there are exceptions sometimes, maybe people see things differently. Maybe a certain amount of unfairness is inevitable.

Though I try to be helpful beside all.

Comment: On following your link to the second question, I was astonished to see that the OP there has awarded a 50-point bounty to the somewhat ridiculous suggestions ["Promiscuous Hussie" and "Polyamorous"](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/155529/2637) for *Feminine equivalent for Casanova*. But what the hell - I'm closevoting both of them in favour of the much earlier [“Man” is to “womanizer” as “woman” is to what?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69129/). Just because people *like* such questions doesn't mean we need *lots* of them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Hear, hear" on the "female Casanova" bounty. Still makes my [blood boils](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133409/feminine-equivalent-for-casanova/155529#comment326434_133550) when I think about it. ANY other answer was acceptable apart from that one. In my opinion the "femme fatale" is a duplicate of the Casanova one. The OP would have found all the suggestions relevant, if not all he had to do was say so and ask for an answer which HAD NOT already been given in the dupe.

Comment: I am reading with interest all your comments. I was not aware of the 'Casanova' question, but I don't think that it is the same as mine, though the subject may have some points in common. 'Casanova' is more about sex,a 'femme fatal' is more a question about the role between man and woman, with roots far in the past ( Circe). My stress on the fact on 'English' words with respect to 'French ones' was probably not clear enough, or simply interpretations of my questions were different, as it should be I think. Will do my best to be as clear as possible in the future. –  Jack 7 mins ago

Comment: @Jack: Thanks for the feedback. We were also waiting from you to clarify the question and there were recommendations about that. It wasn't late that time but I think it does not matter anymore. I'm sure you will ask great questions next time :)

Comment: @Jack - Remember that SE works with votes.  When all people vote on things, don't try to make sense of it.

Comment: Note the word "questions" in "Duplicate questions". The answers are irrelevant: it's only a duplicate if the **questions** ask the same thing. (I know some people here disagree with that, but they're wrong.)

Comment: I misread that as **Do popular people and their answers get exceptions?** My first thought was, sometimes, but it is MUCH more of a problem on certain other SE sites than here.

Answer (score 3):

I never actually voted on the "incorrect empathy" question, but I did post a couple of comments trying to establish the relevance of the word "empathy".

The OP's response (in comments and edited question text) clearly indicate that empathy actually has no relevance at all - it's just about one person not properly understanding another's situation, because they're inappropriately viewing it from a personal/parochial perspective.

Although I didn't *closevote*, I won't vote to *re-open* either, unless the question is further clarified. As it stands, the OP *seems* to be specifically interested in misunderstandings caused by a *privileged* person's subjective assessment, but for all I know he might actually be interested in a more general term that also covers misunderstandings caused by subjective assessment from a *deprived* perspective (some poor people find it difficult to appreciate that wealthy people can also feel dissatisfied with life, for example).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I answered that question before he edited (because the title and the interrogative sentence is what I focused on, the example was not clear enough at first. It could be a general question about false empathy with a simple example also) but my last paragraph in the answer is related to his example and associated with empathy. Also I came up with another idea after he edited and mentioned in the comments, I was waiting his confirmation but then I saw that question was put on hold. Also, empathy is a very broad concept in psychology and the source book has a lot of details.